# Sharepoint task process with serial wise user

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-designer

### Sharepoint task process problem:

I have a workflow. I want to create a task for multiple user. But task will be created serial wise. For example, a people picker field and i selected 3 users (User 1, user 2, user 3).But i need to task create which order i give. if i give user 1, user 2, user 3 then first task create user 1 then user 2 etc. Is it possible in SharePoint designer workflow task create ? it is urgent needed.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, I understand you want to send task to users serially.

In the workflow, choose Serial(one at a time).

[image]

Comment: I used it. But problem is it automatically sort id of given user descending order. But I want 
which order I give , task will be creared that order.

Comment: I don't think it's possible,